# Implement get_serializer in generic list view (generics.ListCreateAPIView) in Django REST Framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have a `PageSerializer` that inherits from `DynamicFieldsModelSerializer` which I copied from  the docs (http://django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers.html#dynamically-modifiying-fields). To initialize the serializer from my generic view I implemented `get_serializer`. For my detail view (which inherits from `generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView`) this works fine, but when I try to initialize my `PageSerializer` in the list view (which inherits from `generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView`) I get the following error:

```
'PageList' should either include a 'serializer_class' attribute,
or use the 'model' attribute as a shortcut for automatically generating
a serializer class.
```

Here's my get_serializer implementation (which I implemented in the list view as well as in the detail view)

```
def get_serializer(self, instance=None, data=None, files=None, many=False, partial=False):
    fields = None
    if self.request.method == 'GET':
        query_fields = self.request.QUERY_PARAMS.get("fields", None)

        if query_fields:
            fields = tuple(query_fields.split(','))

    return PageSerializer(instance=instance, data=data, files=files, many=many, partial=partial, fields=fields)
```

Judging from the error message get_serializer doesn't seem go get used. Is there a different way to achieve this for a list view? I haven't managed to find any hints as to how get_serializer should be used.

Answer (score 1):

The error you are seeing is because you didn't declare a `serializer_class` or `model` attribute on your view.  If you don't specify those you must override `get_serializer_class()` to tell the view which serializer to use.

Also you said:

> but when I try to initialize my PageSerializer in the list view (which inherits from generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView) I get the following error:

A list view should inherit from one of the generic list views like `ListCreateAPIView`, not a single object view like `RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView`.